# Laravel 5.7 Custom Login Not Working - New Installation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

I have a new installation of laravel 5.7
I have created the database and users table with dummy info manually and connected the database with the application.

Can anyone please point out why the following code isn't working.

login.blade.php

```
        <div class="form box">
           <h1 align="center">Login - MobileInfo</h1>
           <br />

           @if(isset(Auth::user()->username))
                <script>window.location="main/success"</script>
           @endif

           @if ($message = Session::get('error'))
           <div class="alert alert-danger alert-block">
               <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">x</button>
               <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
           </div>
           @endif

           @if (count($errors) > 0)
           <div class="alert alert-danger">
               <ul>
                   @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                   <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                   @endforeach
               </ul>
           </div>

           @endif
            <form method="post" action="{{ url('login/checklogin') }}">
                {{ csrf_field()}}
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Username</label>
                    <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" />
                </div>
                 <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" name="login" class="btn btn-primary" value="Login" />
                </div>
            </form>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Login Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Validator;
use Auth;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
public function index()
{
    return view ('login');
}

function checklogin(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'username' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required'
    ]);

    $user_data = array(
        'username' => $request->get('username'),
        'password' => $request->get('password')
    );

    if(Auth::attempt($user_data))
    {
        return redirect('login/success');
    }
    else
    {
        return back()->with('error', 'Wrong Login Details');
    }
}

function success()
{
    return view('dashboard');
}

function logout()
{
    Auth::logout();
    return redirect('login');
}
}
```

web.php

```
Route::get('/', 'LoginController@index');
Route::post('login/checklogin', 'LoginController@checklogin');
Route::get('login/success', 'LoginController@success');
Route::get('login/logout', 'LoginController@logout');
```

The error I see after adding any of the correct combinations of username/password is the else block of Auth::attempt($user_data), that is "Wrong Login Details".

Comment: Auth::login($user_data) instead of Auth::attempt()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel store passwords using its hashing algorithm and then validate/compare with same hashing algorithm.

The problem is, you stored literal passwords in database, that's why laravel is unable to validate those passwords. Laravel is expecting hashed password from database.

Literal password won't work. So ...

**#1**

Best solution is, make a signup form as well (using laravel Auth) and insert demo data through that signup form. Laravel will store passwords after hashing it, and eventually successfully validating those passwords.

**#2**

Another(complex/tedious) solution is, find out laravel's hashing algorithm and hash passwords with a separate php script. Then store hashed passwords in database directly. You don't need signup form in this case because you are doing it manually.

**Update for solution # 2**

Use below code to hash your literal passwords in laravel 5.x.

```
$hashedpassword = bcrypt('plaintextpassword');
```

Comment: Yes, you are correct about the literal password problem. I have not used migrate and db:seed to insert data into the database and it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Laravel auth provide authentification with email, so to use another field to login, you may define it in LoginController.

```
public function username()
{
    return 'username';
}
```

[Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authentication#authentication-quickstart)

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer - why do you think that it solves the problem?